# Facing an issue while trying to install Jenkins with PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am using below script for Jenkins installation on Windows server.

```
# Create a new local user account for running Jenkins
$userName = 'jenkins'
$userPassword = 'P@ssw0rd' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $userPassword)
New-LocalUser -Name $userName -Password $userPassword

# Download the latest Jenkins WAR file
$jenkinsUrl = 'http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/jenkins.war'
$jenkinsPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $jenkinsUrl -OutFile $jenkinsPath

# Create a new Jenkins service that runs under the jenkins user account
$serviceName = 'Jenkins'
$binaryPath = "C:\Windows\System32\java.exe -jar $jenkinsPath --httpPort=8080"
$serviceParams = @{
    Name = $serviceName
    BinaryPathName = $binaryPath
    Credential = $credential
    Description = 'Jenkins CI server'
}
New-Service @serviceParams
Start-Service $serviceName
```

Error:

```
New-Service : Service ' (Jenkins)' cannot be created due to the following error:
The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Service @serviceParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Jenkins:String) [New-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotNewService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewServiceCommand
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Is there a password policy requiring, say, longer password than 8 characters? Also see if there's more sensible error message in the Event logs.

Comment: Well, I tried with a password more than 8 character as well. Its still the same.